# How create an icon menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have this problem:

The standard command that I use to put an icon is:

```
<a href="" class="icon fa-file-code-o"></a>
```

But this code just have space for 1 link (I did not found other examples), but I need to redirect for multiple chooses. I.e. What I want to know is if it is possible to create a ``menu" from an icon, something like that:
When I click on the icon they show all the options for the person, like an standard menu

[image: Like this]

If is relevant, the icons are on one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it involves more HTML for the menu, CSS to show 2 states: hidden and showing, and JavaScript for the click event handling.

> *"(I did not found other examples)"*

I'm going to assume that is true considering your grasp of English. Before you say it *"doesn't work"*, you must post the code that you are working with: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/jQuery. Please keep it to a minimum and we'll request more or less as your question progresses.

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('.fa').onclick = openClose;

function openClose(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") {
    e.target.classList.toggle('on');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: fit-content;
}

.on + .menu {
  max-height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.menu a {
    color:#FC3;
    text-decoration:none
}

.menu li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<a href="#/" class="fa fa-file-code-o fa-3x"></a>
<ul class='menu'>
  <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html'>HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css'>CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript'>JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I want! Sorry by I do not provide a MWE, I was using the `<nav>`, which does not provide the desired result, I did not know that I could use `href="/#"`  to redirect it for a `<li>` with Java. And your code is the first time that I see this construction, when I searched on google, I just found examples and explanations with the `<nav>` environment, maybe because I searched with the word ``menu"...

Comment: That's great, I'm glad you got it so fast. I have to admit I never looked for  something like that before and I don't recall ever seeing it in passing either.Your description with the img was enough to make it on the fly.  Happy coding. BTW `href="#/"` is just a way to disable it's default behavior to jump to a location. That icon/`<a>` is merely a button that has `cursor:pointer` built-in and a series of typical pseudo-classes that change its colors [**L**o**V**e and **HA**te](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/)

Answer (score 0):

In general, one does not "create a menu from an icon", you normally create a menu and an icon to it. Your "standard command" is an ordinary HTML-Link with some custom attributes that are then processed by some package running in your environment to create a menu. But without more info about your environment, it is impossible to give an accurate and satisfying answer.

Comment: Sorry about it... As I did not know how to start this construction I asked for a _general method_ to construct it, not a specific problem with a code, or even, an attempt _code_, as I said to zer00ne, I was trying with the `<nav>`, but did not work. Maybe I misunderstand you (and others) with the use of **menu**, by the way, fortunately I received a solution.